# How to print a column of a random line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm doing homework and need help on shell script or `nano` editor. 
The output should be:

```
[NAME], [YEAR] 
[RATING] 
[DESCRIPTION]
```

Where the fields marked in square brackets correspond to the values ​​of the fields of a movie randomly chosen from those available in the *file.csv* file.

The problem is that I cannot not print them separately, I can only print a random line.

I've tried to separated them using the command `cut -d " " -f1` but it didn't work.

```
cat file.csv | wc -l
LINES=$(cat file.csv | wc-l)
R_LINE=$(($RANDOM % LINES))
sed -n "${R_LINE}p" file.csv
echo "NAME: "....., "YEAR:..... "
echo "RATING:..... "
echo "DESCRIPTION:......"
```

Comment: We have no idea what your input file looks like. You can split on commas with `IFS=',' read -r` or maybe just simpiy switch to Awk instead.

Comment: Could you post some data for us?

Comment: `sort -R file.csv | awk -F ',' '{ print "uppercase shouting NAME:", $1, ", year: "$2, print "rating:", $3; print "description:", $4; exit 0 }'` though if the description could contain commas, too, you need a more sophisticated CSV parser.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using awk:

```
LINES=$(cat file.csv | wc-l)
R_LINE=$(($RANDOM % LINES))
awk -FS="," 'NR=='$R_LINE'{printf("NAME: %s, YEAR: %d\n\nRATING:%s\n\nDESCRIPTION:%s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4);exit}' file.csv
```

This code assumes that the attributes in `file.csv` are listed in the order `name,year,rating,description`. If you have a different order, change the column numbers in the `printf` statement accordingly.

Comment: Instead of `cat file.csv | wc-l`, consider `wc -l < file.csv`.